# CSRS to NAD83 datum shift with ogr2ogr using grid shift file fails

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr

I am trying to do a datum shift transformation using ogr2ogr on the Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 command line. All files, including the grid shift file, are in the same directory. I run the following command:

> ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -s_srs "+proj=utm +zone=17 +ellps=GRS80
>   +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +nadgrids=ON83CSv1.gsb" -t_srs EPSG:26917 survey_marker_NAD83.shp
>   survey_marker_csrs.shp

I get the following error:

> ERROR 1: failed to load datum shift file
>   Failed to reproject feature 0 (geometry probably out of source or destination SRS).
>   ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
>   translation of layer survey_marker_csrs (use -skipfailures to skip errors)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I solved it! In Linux you do not give the entire path to the grid file, just ./ will suffice. The following command worked:

> ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -s_srs "+proj=utm +zone=17 +ellps=GRS80
>   +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +nadgrids=./ON83CSv1.gsb" -t_srs EPSG:26917 outfile.shp infile.shp